# Get count of Django queryset by today's date

Tags: django, orm

I have a Django project with a model that looks like this:

```
    class sellerprod(models.Model):
        prod = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
        date = models.DateField(db_index=True, default=datetime.date.today, null=True, blank=True)
        company = models.ForeignKey(company, db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

In my views I import datetime and define NOW = date.datetime.now().  I want to get the count of all the records in the table that have today's date.  I have tried this (and some other similar variations):

```
sellercount = sellerprod.objects.filter(date=NOW.date()).count()
```

The table in my PostgreSQL database has a total of 62 records and only 28 have today's date, but this query gives me the total count of 62.

I have a different view, which actually retrieves the data rather than a count, and it correctly gets 24 records (there are four less matching records with a company_id of 2) with this:

```
products = sellerprod.objects.filter(date=NOW.date(), company__companyid=2)
```

I presume that I am doing something wrong that causes me to get a count of all my records rather than just those with today's date.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks--

Al

Comment: What is `NOW` here? Can you add the reference to the variable?

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that I had a typo in my views.  All is well now.